# Diagram with a shaded region

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading

[image]

The following MWE yields the diagram above but I would like to find a better way of showing the shaded region.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[fill=black!20!white] (0,2)--(2,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;
        \draw (0,0) --node[below] {$2x$}(2,0)--node[below] {$\vphantom{2}x$}(3,0)--(3,2)--(0,2)-- node[left] {$x-7$}cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note that the top left corner does not look pretty. Am thinking about clipping but seems a bit too much.

Answer (score 11):

You can exploit the `path picture` key of the nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[fill=black!20!white] (0,2)--(2,0)--(3,0)--(3,2)--cycle;
    \draw (0,0) --node[below] {$2x$}(2,0)--node[below] {$\vphantom{2}x$}(3,0)--(3,2)--(0,2)-- node[left] {$x-7$}cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=2cm, inner sep=0pt, fill=white,draw, path picture={%
        \fill[black!20]($(path picture bounding box.south)!.35!(path picture bounding box.south east)$) coordinate(a)--
        (path picture bounding box.north west)--
        (path picture bounding box.north east)|-
        (path picture bounding box.south); % filling
        \draw (a)--(path picture bounding box.north west);% line
    }] (x) at (0,0){};
    \node[left=2pt] at (x.west){$x-7$};
    \node[below] at ($(x.south)!.35!(x.south west)$){$2x$};
    \node[below] at ($(x.south)!.65!(x.south east)$){$\vphantom{2}x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Quite interesting! Thought clipping was the only way although I didn't do it that way.

Comment: @azetina: of course, but clipping is too simple and not much esoteric ;)

Answer (score 4):

A PSTricks solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\psset{linejoin = 1}

\def\Label[#1](#2)(#3)#4{%
  \pcline[linestyle = none, offset = #1](#2)(#3)
  \ncput{#4}}

% parameters
\def\width{6}
\def\height{4}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-0.93,-0.4)(\width,\height)
  \pnodes{P}(0,0)(0,\height)(\width,\height)(\width,0)(!2 3 div \width\space mul 0)
  \pspolygon(P0)(P1)(P4)
  \pspolygon[
    fillstyle = solid,
    fillcolor = gray!50
  ](P1)(P2)(P3)(P4)
  \Label[15pt](P0)(P1){$x - 7$}
  \Label[-7pt](P0)(P4){$2x$}
  \Label[-7pt](P4)(P3){$x$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

All you have to do is change the values of the parameters and the drawing will by adjusted accordingly.

Comment: But you have the same problem with the top left corner as the OP

Comment: @JMP Just corrected; I noticed it immediately after I posted my answer. (I missed `\psset{linejoin = 1}`.)

Answer (score 1):

For comparison with [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) and [luamplib](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).  Compile with `lualatex`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
u = 1mm;
x = 20u;

path box, shade;
box = unitsquare xscaled 3x yscaled 2x;
shade = subpath (2/3,3) of box -- cycle;

fill shade withcolor .8 white;
draw subpath (3,4) of shade;
draw box;

label.bot("$2x$",  point 1/3 of box);
label.bot("$x$",   point 5/6 of box);
label.lft("$x-7$", point 7/2 of box);

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- The built-in path `unitsquare` has four "points" corresponding to the the four corners and numbered clockwise from zero starting at the bottom left.  Hence `point 2/3 of box` is 2/3 of the way along the bottom edge, and `point 7/2 of box` is halfway down the left hand edge.
- `subpath (x,y) of path` runs from `point x of path` to `point y of path`.
- It's tempting to "correct" the diagram to draw it to scale.  If you replace the line defining the `box` with

  ```
  box = unitsquare xscaled 3x yscaled (x-7u);
  ```

  then you get this slightly more believable figure.

[image]